# Set up zend project in live server

Tags: php, zend-framework

Actually, I have created account in  000webhost.com free hosting, I uploaded system successfully. But I am able to run it only through this link aubergeikaze.netne.net/public/. The server is based on Apache:

```
//////////////////////.htaccess file \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working

RewriteBase /
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

How can I configure http://aubergeikaze.netne.net/public/ to http://aubergeikaze.netne.net/ server in Apache. Thanks

Comment: How can we help you when you provide almost no detail to your question? Be more specific, and don't assume everyone has a crystal ball.

Comment: oh, sorry for this. let me improve it

Comment: Is it clear now, what else you may want to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is documented in [Zend Framework on a shared host](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/zend-framework-on-a-shared-host/)

Essentially, you need an `index.php` and a `.htaccess` file in the root folder as that's where Apache is serving from.

index.php:

```
<?php 
define('RUNNING_FROM_ROOT', true);
include 'public/index.php';
```

.htaccess:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

You'll also need to sort out the paths to static assets like CSS and JS files. You can either change the paths to include `public/` or write a plugin to to it for you.

Another option as noted in the comments to this answer (formatted here for readability):

Create an .htaccess file into root folder with this content:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ="" 
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php
```

Comment: Thank you for you feedback, I already got it solved. I just moved  .htaccess file into root folder and change it to:RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

Options -Indexes