# Setting Up Zend Framework 2 On A Live Server

Tags: zend-framework2

i am attempting to set up my **first Live site** on a live server, i am using a shared hosting account so i was not able to change my DocumentRoot to point at the public/ folder of the website .

i did however follow the advice [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193640/set-up-zend-project-in-live-server) and  made two files in the root of the site;

> index.php and a .htaccess

unfortunately my site has gone completely blank; nothing is being rendered. i wonder therefore if there is something else i need to do to make the classes render.

this is my index.php file

```
define('RUNNING_FROM_ROOT', true);
include 'public/index.php';
```

**This is my .htaccess file**

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ="" 
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php
```

Comment: how are you hosting the site as sub domain or primary domain or sub folder access, sub folder access won't work in shared hosting as all reference to zf2 are from / [root]

Comment: White page usually means a php error.  Try adding `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` to your index.php file to see what's really going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions you followed is written for ZF1.

Try to create a new .htaccess file in your public folder like below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

This is recommended way for apache2 in [Zend Skeleton Application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/public/.htaccess). Since you don't want to do extremely different things, it should work.

Comment: Hi Foozy. thanks for the response. i tried it but it does not work. I am still getting a blank page though

Comment: i do however, feel that the problem is with the zendframework. for example, if i echo "test" from the index page wihin my public folder, it does indeed echo test.

Comment: hi Foozy. you are a genius. thanks for your help . its working now

Answer (score 0):

It would be due to white spaces in the code.
To remove white spaces you can use this 
[PHP CS Fixer](https://github.com/fabpot/PHP-CS-Fixer)